# I have 4 buttons with a Javascript that open 4 php pages with video inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

I have an embedded video player inside a DIV... I have 4 buttons that open 4 different PHP pages (with a video player on each) that open inside a single DIV. The idea is to have a player that changes flawlessly between those 4 channels. My problem is that when I click on the buttons, only the first page (and video) stays open and playing. If I click a different button, only the first page stays open. The problem seems to be that my Javascript works only for one link. How can I implement that, when I click on a different button, the first page stops to let the second page load.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    $("#pantalla").load("/screen-spa.php");
  });
});
</script>
        
<span class="button"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage(rootdomain+'/screen-eng.php', 'pantalla');">Music videos</a></span>

        
<span class="button"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage(rootdomain+'/screen-mov.php', 'pantalla');">Movie clips</a></span>    


<span class="button"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage(rootdomain+'/screen-tvs.php', 'pantalla');">TV shows</a></span>


<span class="button"><a href="javascript:ajaxpage(rootdomain+'/screen-spa.php', 'pantalla');">Música en español</a></span>
```

Comment: can you provide a working snippet of what you have?  Why not just change the video?

Comment: This is basically what I have. it is a main page with a screen. The idea is to have visitors click on different options, and change the videos in the same central screen. I don't want them to open a new page.

Comment: seems like `$("#pantalla").load("/screen-spa.php");` overrides `href="javascript:ajaxpage`.

Comment: Provide a working snippet of what you have

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but you should get the page URL from its attribute.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    var address = $(this).attr("data-address");
    $("#pantalla").load(address);
  });
});
</script>

<button class="button" data-address="/screen-eng.php">Music videos</button>

<button class="button" data-address="/screen-mov.php">Movie clips</button>
...
```

1. Add `data-address` attribute with value of your page address
2. Get current attribute by using `$(this).attr("data-address")`

But I recommend to use this code instead:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<button class="btn" data-lang="en">English</button>

<button class="btn" data-lang="fa">Persian</button>

<button class="btn" data-lang="fr">French</button>

<div id="page"></div>

<script>
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        let lang = $(this).attr("data-lang");
        $("#page").load("ajax.php?lang=" + lang);
    });
</script>
```

then on your server-side handle the request:

```
// ajax.php
# check if the lang parameter is set in the URL or set "en" language by default
$lang = $_GET['lang'] ?? "en";

if( $lang == "en" ){
    ?>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtube.com/embed/D6Ac5JpCHmI?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <?php
}
else if( $lang == "fa" ){
    ?>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtube.com/another/video?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <?php
}
else if( $lang == "fr" ){
    ?>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtube.com/one/more/video?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <?php
}
```

## Edit

Just add some youtube embedded video player in your PHP and manage them by sending GET to your server.

There is no need to create multiple pages for each video, just add your video URL like this code and get whichever you want by sending a GET request like this:

`http://example.com/ajax.php?lang=en`

Comment: Thank you. What I'm trying to do is this: I have a central embedded Youtube player (just one screen) with a few buttons below. I want for users to be able to click on those buttons, and change the player without changing the whole page, just like changing channels.

Comment: I have edited my answer, if it didn't help you tell me more about your project. I will help you as much as I can

Comment: Thank you Hossein. I have been trying to use your solution in different ways, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: It's not very complicated, maybe you are doing it in a wrong way, share your code and I will check it for you

Comment: Maybe it's not complicated, but my knowledge is very limited. I have these pages:  test-2.php and ajax.php

Comment: I have posted another answer, check if that's what you want

Answer (score 0):

I decided to send another answer with more specifications.

**Step 1**

Create your buttons with `data-lang` attribute with the value of your language. Let's name it `channels.php`:

```
<!-- data-lang="en": English -->
<button class="btn" data-lang="en">English</button>

<!-- data-lang="fa": Persian (farsi) -->
<button class="btn" data-lang="fa">Persian</button>

<!-- data-lang="fr": French -->
<button class="btn" data-lang="fr">French</button>
```

**Step 2**

Add some jQuery to your `channel.php` file:

```
<script>
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        // Get data-lang attribute from clicked element
        let lang = $(this).attr("data-lang");

        // Send a GET request to your ajax.php file
        $("#page").load("ajax.php?lang=" + lang);
        // or it can be the URL of your ajax file
        // it's something like this: http://example.com/ajax.php?lang=en
    });
</script>
```

**Step 3**
Now your `ajax.php` should be something like this:

```
# check if the lang parameter is set in the URL or set "en" language by default
$lang = $_GET['lang'] ?? "en";

# If the language is English
if( $lang == "en" ){
    echo "English content";
}
# If the language is Farsi
else if( $lang == "fa" ){
    echo "Farsi content";
}
# If the language is French
else if( $lang == "fr" ){
    echo "French content";
}
```

You have to replace your content with `echo "... content";` for each language.

I'm not sure how much you know about php, but you can put some HTML codes between PHP without using `echo`, just close PHP tag, write your HTML, then reopen php tag:

```
<?php

# some php codes

?>

<h1>HTML content</h1>

<?php

# Some more php contents

?>
```

in this case, it's something like this:

```
if( true ){
   # Closing PHP tag
   ?>
   <!-- Writing HTML contents -->
   <h1>HTML content</h1>
   <?php
   # Then reopen PHP tag
}
```

Finally, you can put your embedded HTML Youtube player instead using echo:

```
if( $lang == "en" ){
    ?>
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://youtube.com/vide/url?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <?php
}
```

I hope this was helpful